# How to use regex in string partition using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a string like as shown below from a pandas data frame column

```
string = "insulin MixTARD  30/70 -  inJECTable 20 unit(s)  SC (SubCutaneous)     -   Hypoglycaemia Protocol if Blood Glucose Level (mmol)  <  4     -   Call Doctor if Blood Glucose Level (mmol)  >  22"
```

I am trying to get an output like as shown below (you can see everything before 2nd hyphen is returned)

```
insulin MixTARD  30/70 -  inJECTable 20 unit(s)  SC (SubCutaneous)
```

So, I tried the below code

```
string.partition('   -')[0]  # though this produces the output, not reliable
```

Meaning, I always want everything before the 2nd `Hyphen` (`-`).

Instead of me manually assigning the spaces, I would like to write something like below. Not sure whether the below is right as well. can you help me get everything before the 2nd hyphen?

```
string.partition(r'\s{2,6}-')[0]
```

Can help me get the expected output using `partition method and regex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `re.sub` here for a one-liner solution:

```
string = "insulin MixTARD  30/70 -  inJECTable 20 unit(s)  SC (SubCutaneous)     -   Hypoglycaemia Protocol if Blood Glucose Level (mmol)  <  4     -   Call Doctor if Blood Glucose Level (mmol)  >  22"
output = re.sub(r'^([^-]+?-[^-]+?)(?=\s*-).*$', '\\1', string)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
insulin MixTARD  30/70 -  inJECTable 20 unit(s)  SC (SubCutaneous)
```

Explanation of regex:

```
^               from the start of the input
    (           capture
        [^-]+?  all content up to
        -       the first hyphen
        [^-]+?  all content up, but not including
    )           end capture
    (?=\s*-)    zero or more whitespace characters followed by the second hyphen
    .*          then match the remainder of the input
$               end of the input
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `re.split` instead of `string.partition`:

```
re.split(r'\s{2,6}-', string)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution with `split` and `join`:

```
"-".join(string.split("-")[0:2])
```